# How can I display a green cell if result is true or a green robot image when result is true in SQL Server Reporting Services

Tags: sql-server, ssrs-2012

I want the result of my SQL query, which gives a True or False as result currently, to display a green cell if result is true or a green robot image when result is true and to display a Red cell if result is false or a red robot image when result is false in SQL Server Reporting Services.

The script works perfectly but I do not know how to do the above mentioned.

Thank you in advance!

Here is an example of what it currently looks like:

[image: SSRS Current Table Example]

Here is an example of what it should look like:

[image: SSRS Proposed Table Example]

Answer (score 4):

you can set the background color for every cell in its property. In this property is option - `function`. in opened window write something like that: `=iif(YourField=true,"White","Red")`. where `YourField` you can select in `Recordset`

Comment: Thanks!! This helped alot!!